# How to align footer columns foundation zurb

Tags: zurb-foundation, footer, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to create footer navigation. I followed a video from Gary Jennings. I copied everything that he did in both HTML and CSS. My footer is not aligning horizontally but in a column stacked on top of each other. I need my footer to have 3 columns set next to each other.

This is what one of the sections or "columns" looks like in the code.
[code view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtEaF.png)

[website view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOfWW.png)

Comment: Hi, please use the tag `zurb-foundation` instead of `foundation`.

Comment: Please provide more details like the Foundation Sites version that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Equalizer as in the Zurb Site Docs:

```
    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x" data-equalizer data-equalize-on="medium" id="test-eq">
  <div class="cell medium-4">
    <div class="callout" data-equalizer-watch>
      <img src= "assets/img/generic/square-1.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell medium-4">
    <div class="callout" data-equalizer-watch>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et, ante.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell medium-4">
    <div class="callout" data-equalizer-watch>
      <img src= "assets/img/generic/rectangle-1.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```